# strip panels lattice

Tags: r, lattice

My problem is to strip my panels with lattice framework.

```
testData<-data.frame(star=rnorm(1200),frame=factor(rep(1:12,each=100))
                     ,n=factor(rep(rep(c(4,10,50),each=100),4))
                     ,var=factor(rep(c("h","i","h","i"),each=300))
                     ,stat=factor(rep(c("c","r"),each=600))
 )
levels(testData$frame)<-c(1,7,4,10,2,8,5,11,3,9,6,12)# order of my frames
histogram(~star|factor(frame), data=testData
            ,as.table=T
            ,layout=c(4,3),type="density",breaks=20
            ,panel=function(x,params,...){
               panel.grid()
               panel.histogram(x,...,col=1)     
               panel.curve(dnorm(x,0,1), type="l",col=2)
              }
 )
```

What I'm looking for, is:
[image: striped plot]

Comment: You could add labels outside of R, but you should first check to see if the placement of the panels agrees with that labeling. I constructed a graph with strip labels generated by pasting "var" and "stat" and there were mixtures of "h" and "i" within the right and left halves of that graphic.

Comment: You can see this effect yourself by just adding this expression to your 'star' values `+  rep(c(-2,2), each=600)` and redrawing your plot. If your placement theory were correct, all of the left-hand side plots should be shifted tot he same side of 0. They are not.

Comment: sry I dont really get you. I know the strip attribute but I dont know how to change it in the right way. what is really close to what Iam looking for is:

Comment: h<-histogram(~star|factor(paste(var,stat))+factor(n), data=testData
            ,as.table=T
            ,layout=c(4,3),type="density",breaks=20
            ,panel=function(x,params,...){
               panel.grid()
               panel.histogram(x,...,col=1)     
               panel.curve(dnorm(x,0,1), type="l",col=2)
              }
    )
    plot(h)
    useOuterStrips(h,strip.left = strip.custom(horizontal = FALSE))

But there are some questions left.
-how create a strip over to rows
-how to use the properties, they updated with useOuterStrips directly in the histogram function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to add the factor call around items in the conditioning section of the formula when they are already factors. If you want to make a cross between two factors the `interaction` function is the best approach. It even has a 'sep' argument which will accept a new line character. This is the closest I can produce:

```
h<-histogram(~star|interaction(stat, var,  sep="\n") + n, data=testData  , 
              as.table=T ,layout=c(4,3), type="density", breaks=20 ,  
panel=function(x,params,...){ panel.grid() 
panel.histogram(x,...,col=1) 
panel.curve(dnorm(x,0,1), type="l",col=2) } ) 
plot(h) 
useOuterStrips(h,strip.left = strip.custom(horizontal = FALSE), 
                  strip.lines=2, strip.left.lines=1)
```

I get an error when I try to put in three factors separately and then try to use `useOuterStrips`. It won't accept three separate conditioning factors. I've searched for postings in Rhelp, but the only perfectly on-point question got an untested suggestion and when I tried it failed miserably.

Comment: Thx, how to use the properties, they updated with useOuterStrips directly in the histogram function?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What properties? Use in what fashion?

Comment: I want to assign strip.left etc. in the histogram function.

Comment: Look at `useOuterStrips` code. You will need to use `modifyList` on the strip component of `standard.theme(.Device)`. You also need to provide strip and strip.left that are properly constructed. Doing this in a general way would involve rewriting most of `useOuterStrips` within your histogram call. It does not seem worth the aggravation.